# Действия с двухмерным массивом (Java)

Tags: java, массивы

Дан двухмерный массив nxn заполненный случайными буквами английского алфавита.
Вот таким образом:

```
public static char[][] sozdanieMassiva(int razmerMassiva){
    char[][] massiv = new char[razmerMassiva][razmerMassiva];
    for(int i = 0; i<massiv.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < massiv[i].length; j++){
            massiv[i][j] = sluchainajaBukva();
            //System.out.printf("%5c", massiv[i][j]);
        }
        //System.out.println();
    }
    return massiv;
}
```

К нему есть несколько заданий. 
Следующие:
*Каких букв больше гласных или согласных
*Сколько раз встречается каждый символ в матрице
*Выделите определенным цветом символы, которые встречаются 1 раз (распечатайте индексы расположения элементов)
*Есть ли строки или столбцы, где набор символов повторяется? Если да, то распечатайте номера строк или столбцов

Первое я решила следующим образом:

```
public static void glasnqeSoglasnqe(char[][] massiv){
    int chetchikGlasnqh = 0;
    int chetchikSoglasnqh = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<massiv.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < massiv[i].length; j++){
            if (massiv[i][j] == 'A' || massiv[i][j] == 'E' ||
                    massiv[i][j] == 'I' || massiv[i][j] == 'O' ||
                    massiv[i][j] == 'U' || massiv[i][j] == 'a' ||
                    massiv[i][j] == 'e' || massiv[i][j] == 'i' ||
                    massiv[i][j] == 'o' || massiv[i][j] == 'u') {
                chetchikGlasnqh++;
            } else {
                chetchikSoglasnqh++;
            }
    }
    }
    System.out.println("" + chetchikGlasnqh);
    System.out.println("" + chetchikSoglasnqh);
    if(chetchikGlasnqh>chetchikSoglasnqh){
        System.out.println("Гласных букв больше");
    }else if(chetchikGlasnqh<chetchikSoglasnqh){
        System.out.println("Согласных букв больше.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("В массиве равное количество гласных и согласных.");
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** возможно ли решить следующие задания как-то по другому, кроме как простым сравнением каждого символа в массиве с каждой отдельной буквой? Если да, то как?

Comment: я бы наверное гласные буквы просто в строку определил в верхний (или нижний) регистр, при проверке переводил бы символ в строку (а в принципе если условие задачи не запрещает делал бы все в String) и проверял вхождение строки в подстроку гласных

Comment: можно сделать стримами. а еще писать вложенные циклы с целью поиска элементов одного множества в другом - не есть хорошо. есть другие решения. к примеру, привести одно множество к хешированой коллекции (сет). в этом случае сложность определения наличия элемента в коллекции О(1). представьте, что у вас 2 массива по 100 элементов каждый. тогда для проверки в худшем случае надо 100*100 циклов, т.е. 10_000 итераций. при этом за 100 итераций вы можете преворатить массив в сет и еще за сто выполнить прверку. получается всего 200 итераций.